# Extract array values as Typescript types

Tags: typescript

Basically is there a way to extract array values as a string types? Here is the pseudo code:

```
class A
{
    public keys = ['name', 'age']
}

type ArrayKeys = P in A['keys'] // 'name' or 'age'
```

How to narrow ArrayKeys to be with possible values of A['keys'].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to assure TypeScript that `keys` will not change by adding an `as const` cast (otherwise, TypeScript will just assume it's a string array), note that this will make TypeScript enforce this. You will not be able to change the array.

After that, it's fairly simple:

```
class A
{
    public keys = ['name', 'age'] as const
}

type ArrayKeys = A['keys'][number];
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBQBve1XQA4FcBGICWw0A1gKYCeMAvNANoDkAdmALYl0A00dYA5mwLrRI0YAHsGEAC7wAvvHiSy6EnABOqsGQDS5KnHqkKdfjQaZm2Eqv4BuIA).

The `[number]` part is the "accessing" of the array's value. `(Array<T>)[number]` will always be `T`.

Comment: This is beautiful :) ! But can you elaborate on this (Array<T>)[number] part. Where I can read about it what is this at all :) ? Is this Typescript construction or ?

Comment: Let's say you have a variable `x: string[]`, if you access any number index on `x`, you will get a value of type `string` (`const y: string = x[0];`). Therefore, `AnyArray[number]` will get you the type of the value of the elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I don't think you can literally do that, since of course types are a static compile-time feature and arrays are a dynamic runtime feature.</s> ...unless you add `const` as [Madara Uchiha shows us](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56937826/157247).

But you could use a string enum instead of an array, and then get its values to fill in the array.

```
enum ArrayKeys {
    name, age
}
class A {
    public keys = Object.keys(ArrayKeys).filter(key => isNaN(Number(key)));
}
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAggTnAhgTwNLGQZygbwFBSFQiITAA0UiA5sHgL54DGANoptjLgUQA5gAjFgEsmUANYZsAXigB5AQCtgTAC4A6SVgAU8JGikBKdQDNhLVcDjatUaQD4owzADlEL7S8gCrNjIYCAbgY8IA).

This also has the advantage of providing `ArrayKeys.name` and `ArrayKeys.age` as enum values.